# Как ввести строку в поиск на Google?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Программа на андроид должна открыть сайт google.com и в строку поиска ввести строковые данные (строка "новости"). Я создаю неявный интент, указываю его тип - текстовый, вставляю в него текстовую информацию ("новости"), и открываю google.com

```
    Uri address = Uri.parse("http://google.com");
    Intent intentSend = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, address);
    intentSend.setType("text/plain");
    intentSend.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "новости");
    startActivity(intentSend);
```

Сайт нормально открывается. Но я не знаю как переданный текст вставить в строку поиска на сайте. Подскажите, как это сделать?

Comment: ??? а сформировать в коде строку https://www.google.com/search?q=новости нельзя?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы должны использовать QUERY:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, query); // запрос содержит строку поиска
startActivity(intent);
```

[Подробнее о ACTION_WEB_SEARCH](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_WEB_SEARCH)

Или

```
String escapedQuery = URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8");
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/#q=" + escapedQuery);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

[Подробнее об WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

Comment: @Aliskin, видимо я не точно описал задачу. Мне не нужно искать страницы по слову "новости". Мне нужно, чтобы открылся сайт google.com, а в строке поиска находилось слово "новости". Поиск не нужен. Пользователь может сам решить искать или не искать

Comment: Насколько я помню, штатными средствами реализовать на данный момент это невозможно. Некоторые ресурсы реализуют это с помощью сайтов-прокладок, и потом перенаправляют на сайт поисковой службы